# Diagnosing why my PC won't work

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze, desktop-computer

I have a PC I built in 2012 and worked fine for years. However a couple of years it began playing up and I never got it working again because I didn't know what the solution was.

My system:

- [ASUS AM3+ SABERTOOTH 990FX S/L Revision 1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0053GR2HA/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [OCZ OCZ600MXSP-UK ModXStream Pro 600W ATX Power Supply](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B001GLFD54/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [AMD Bulldozer FX-6100 Socket AM3+ 6 Core Processor - 3.30GHz, 3.90GHz Turbo](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005UBNKWO/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [Arctic Cooling Freezer 7 Pro Rev.2 CPU Cooler](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B002G392ZI/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [Corsair CMZ16GX3M4A1600C9B 16GB (4x4GB) 1600MHz CL9 DDR3 Vengeance Blu Memory Four Module Kit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004RFBIUU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [Sapphire 11200-14-20G OC Sapphire Card (2GB, HD7850, GDDR5)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B008HV63F0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- 1x Samsung 2.5-Inch 250 GB 850 EVO Solid State Drive
- 3x [Seagate 3.5 inch 3TB Barracuda Desktop Hard Drives](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0073Q7GU6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- Acetec Wireless N WiFi PCI Adapter Card 300Mbps
- [CiT Vantage Midi Mesh Gaming Case with HD Audio, 4 Fans, Card Reader and No PSU - Black](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0071KZNUY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Basically, when I load up windows 8.1 I can log in and I see the desktop, etc loading up. After a given time of about 2 minutes (from boot) everything freezes! I thought it was my installation of windows or the user account but I've tried loading different user accounts, leaving it to sit at the initial login screen, tried running in safe mode, tried booting from a windows install USB flash drive and every time the PC freezes! The only time it continues to run without freezing is when I am on the bios screen. I thought it could be something running hot but can't feel anything hot across the motherboard.

I loaded it up again a week ago and discovered that one of the 4gb ram sticks doesn't seem to work properly as the bios doesn't recognise it so I removed it and tried booting up as before. Hoping that it was the ram all along it doesn't seem to be as I still get the same old freezing behaviour.

The system has always been slightly fussy in the following ways:
1) The CPU Fan doesn't register the correct RPM - It flickers from 0 to 16000RPM. Solution - set to ignore minimum fan speed in bios.

2) when first booting up the bios usually complains that "overclocking failed! please enter setup to re-configure your system. Press F1 to run setup". Solution - press the reset button and it boots the next time fine.

3) The mobo tends to detect the ram as 1300mhz instead of the 1600mhz. Solution - change in bios.

4) I am wondering if there are any compatibility issues with the mix of hardware as I've noticed some comments from other users on the Amazon product pages -

Originally I had a Samsung 840 Series Pro 128GB 2.5 inch SATA Solid State Drive but it died on me so I replaced it with the 250Gb Evo drive.

Comment: When was the last time you removed the HSF, cleaned the thermal paste off and applied some clean paste?

Comment: spikey_richie - a couple of weeks ago. I monitored the CPU heat yesterday and it didn\t go above 40.C on the bios screen